# writing junit test for specific scenario

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I am trying to write junit for my java web application which uses older command line design pattern (no framework is used for this older application).
I have a scenario in my application.

When the application is deployed in a server, first the server will find the `web.xml` and load and run the `TestDataServlet`(servlet class configured in web.xml  which extends http servlet) before everything gets deployed in the server.

This `TestDataServlet` in turn calls the `TestRunnable` class which is a thread which loads all the properties file (contans informaton about endpoint everything which is used in java classes of my application code) and intialize it before hitting the application in browser.

I am trying to write junit for this application by using one time step up which loads all the properties file before running my junit, so that I can test it easily.

Since my application is not using a framework, I was not able to do it as spring junit does it.

Since there anyway to do it? Could I able to run the `TestDataServlet` before running my junit class?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your TestDataServlet to be able to process a request "isTestRunnableCompleted".  Have the return be true or false.

In your JUnit test, implement the setup() method.  Call the TestDataServlet to start the runnable.  Then, in a while() loop inside the setup() method, every second, call the TestDataServlet to check "isTestRunnableCompleted".  If it is "false", sleep for a second, and then allow the loop to make the call again.  You may want to implement some sort of a timeout in the loop also just in case things go wrong.

Good luck.

```
public class TestDataServlet
{
  public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
    throws ServletException, IOException 
  {
    // Look for some indicator in the request that the caller wants a "status"
    // of the test data being set up
    if ( request.getParameter( "isTestDataRunnableCompleted" ) != null )
    {
      boolean status = testDataRunnableThread.isAlive();

      PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
      writer.println( Boolean.toString( status ) );
      writer.close();       
    }
    else
    {
      // If we get here, then start the test data runnable thread
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rick. Can u explain how to modify TestDataServlet to be able to process a request "isTestRunnableCompleted". Have the return be true or false. Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: Sure.  I've added what an example "doGet" method would look like if it processed both a request for the test data status... and also test data generation.

Comment: Thank you Rick. I will test and let you know the output soon.